# Custom permission class not returning custom permission denied message - DRF

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a custom permission class where I want a custom permission message to be returned. But it is returning the default permission denied message. Below is the custom permission class that I have written:

```
class IsAuthenticatedAndIsLr(BasePermission):
    
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        
        message = "user is not LR"
        
        return request.user.is_authenticated and  request.user.regd_as == "LR"
```

and here is how I am using it on the api:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticatedAndIsLr])
def create_profile(request):
    '''
    this api creates profile for users based
    on their choosen category.
    '''
    
    data = request.data
    
    model_dict = {
        'IND'
    }
    
    try:
      ...
      
      return Response({'message': f'{request.user} isLR'}, status= status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    
    except Exception as e:
      
      return Response({"message": str(e)}, status= status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
```

I have followed the docs method to raise a custom message but for some reason it is not working. Please suggest to me what is the cause of this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update the message of the `PermissionDenied` exception that will be thrown by DRF you need to raise that same exception manually inside the `IsAuthenticatedAndIsLr`. Something like this:

```
from rest_framework.exceptions import PermissionDenied

class IsAuthenticatedAndIsLr(BasePermission):
    
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated:
            return False

        if request.user.regd_as != "LR":
            raise PermissionDenied(detail="user is not LR")

        return True
```

Comment: okay, but the docs was saying about the message variable so I was doing it that way. Anyway thanks